# Проверить корректность скрипта

Tags: ajax, php, wordpress

Если не сложно, проверьте корректность скрипта.

Скрипт не мой, нашел в Интернете, немножко изменил - все работает как надо, но корректно ли это сделано?

Добавление кнопки «Загрузить еще»:

```
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <script>
    var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
    var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
    var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
    </script>
    <div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>
    <div class="preloader">Загружается...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Скрипт асинхронной загрузки:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){

        var $el = $(this),
            $preloader = $('.preloader');
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page': current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://сайт.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // Обработчик
            type: 'POST', // Тип запроса
            data: data, // Данные
            cache: false, // Кэширование
            beforeSend: function( ) { // Действия, которые будут выполнены перед выполнением ajax-запроса
                $el.hide(); 
                $preloader.show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                if( data ) { 
                    $el.before(data); // Вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // Увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    if (current_page == max_pages) {
                        $el.remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    $el.remove(); // Если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }           
        })

        .complete(function() { // Действия, которые будут выполнены после завершения ajax-запроса
            $preloader.hide();
            $el.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Еще изначально было:

```
if (currentPage == maxPages) {
    $el.remove();
}
```

Но так не работало, я заменил на

```
if (current_page == max_pages) {
    $el.remove();
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, все правильно?

Comment: @rodion Откуда вы берёте переменные `current_page` и `max_pages`, с потолка?
Я Вам в достаточной [мере всё расписал](http://hashcode.ru/questions/400773#400776).

Вы совершенно не понимаете логику отдельно взятого куска кода. Удаляете, добавляете - авось что-нибудь заработает.

Подумайте, может быть, программирование это не ваше.

Comment: @romeo это и так не мое, и логики я не понимаю. Мне бы с этим разобраться и моей радости не было бы границ. current_page и max_pages вот откуда http://ssmaker.ru/9ec2f696.png . То есть сейчас все работает, как и хочется, но правильно ли я сделал или намудрил - не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите кавычки `'<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>'`

Используйте короткие теги при выводе (могут быть отключены):

```
<?=serialize($wp_query->query_vars);>
```

id с название `more` куда нагляднее

```
<div id="more">Загрузить ещё</div>
```

**html:**

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <script>
       var posts = '<?=serialize($wp_query->query_vars);?>';
       var current_page = <?=get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?>;
       var max_pages = <?=$wp_query->max_num_pages;?>;
    </script>
    <div id="more">Загрузить ещё</div>
    <div class="preloader">Загружается...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**js:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#more').click(function(){

        var $el = $(this),
            $preloader = $('.preloader'),
            data = {
                'action': 'loadmore',
                'query': posts,
                'page': current_page
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://сайт.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function( ) {
                $el.hide(); // скрываем элемент #more
                $preloader.show(); // показываем .preloader
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(!data) {
                    return; // если данные от сервера не поступили, выходим из функции
                }

                $el.before(data); // добавляем новые посты

                current_page >= max_pages ?  $el.hide() : $el.show();
                current_page++;
            },
            error: function(){
                $el.show(); // показываем #more при ошибке в запросе

                //... можно написать свой обработчик ошибок
            }
        })
        .complete(function() {
                $preloader.hide(); // всегда скрываем  .preloader, т.е. и при success и при error
        });
    });    
});
```

[Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9azthk/12/)

Comment: @rodion Немного подкорректировал ответ и добавил пример.